# PHP redirection from internal pages

Tags: php

I have a simple login system which redirects back to the outside from every internal page, if you arent logged in. (like check_user)

Now i have a problem with one of my pages, since the login.php sits in the main folder of the admin-cp, it's not a problem for most of the pages. But i created a new folder for the news-panel i am using, so of course it wont redirect but i cannot find out whats the problem.

```
    if(!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    die('Please login first! <a href="login.php">Back to login</a>');
}
```

Any suggestions on how to make it applicable to other folders aswell? just copy paste the login.php to that specific folder or what are you suggesting?

Comment: you could put  `die('Please login first! <a href="/login.php">Back to login</a>');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, it takes the full web path, deletes everything after the `/` and adds `login.php`.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    $url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    $url = substr($url , 0, strpos($url , "/")); //should give you just the root website (http://website.com/ or http://localhost/)
    $url += + "login.php" //maybe you need to do "/login.php"

    die("Please login first! <a href='$url'>Back to login</a>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your looking to redirect them, try a root based link. Its a from the top folder down, that way they always get to the page no matter what.

Put the path to the login from the top directory, start with /

Such as

```
die('Please login first! <a href="/login.php">Back to login</a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `login.php` is located in root (ie. http://example.com/login.php), you can add `/` in front so it will be linked back to the root folder (aka **absolute path**) and look for login.php there.

Like so.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
die('Please login first! <a href="/login.php">Back to login</a>');
```

Only `login.php` is a **relative path** which will only look for the file in the current directory.